# How to store strings in global array from stdin without lost them at the end

Tags: arrays, c

Am facing a problem where i cant fix. I am taking inputs from user  in a function and i want this strings to store in a global array in order to check them later with other function.But my problem is that i cant keep this strings "alive". Thing about that am storing the string "global"
when function ends this string doesn't exists in the global array any more. Can anyone give a small example how to keep alive strings in global arrays without losing them after the function that stores them ends ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a struct (class in C++) for storing these strings and you can use dynamic memory allocation (e.g. malloc) for not losing these datas. I mean your global array will be a member of this struct.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use a global character pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *str;

void accessor1(){
    str = "Hello World";
}
void accessor2(){
    printf("%s",str);
}

int main(){
    accessor1();
    accessor2();
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be : Hello World